# Split string according to character-combination/ at `\n`

Tags: c++, string, c++11, parsing, stdvector

What is the right way to split a string like below at a specific character-combination into a string vector?

```
string myString = "This is \n a test. Let's go on. \n Yeah.";
```

split at `"\n"` to get this result:

```
vector<string> myVector = { 
                              "This is ",
                              " a test. Let's go on. ",
                              " Yeah." 
                           }
```

---

I was using *[boost algorithm](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id2728530)* library but now I'd like to achieve this all without using an external library like boost.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp> 

std::vector<std::string> result;
boost::split(result, "This is \n a test. Let's go on. \n Yeah.", 
              boost::is_any_of("\n"), boost::token_compress_on);
```

Comment: why without using a library? Do you mean no third-party library? or also no `std`?

Comment: No, I meant of course that I would like to do without an external libary like boost. Of course I would like to use std `:)`
. I adjusted my question. @user463035818

Comment: Loop, start and end position, [`string::find('\n', startpos)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find), and `vector::emplace_back(substr(startpos, endpos - startpos))` is one possible option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Solution 1:** Just to remove `"\n"` from the string.

Just to remove `"\n"`, you can use [*erase-remove idiom*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) . [**SEE LIVE HERE**](https://www.ideone.com/IUgyml)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
   std::string myString = "This is \n a test. Let's go on. \n Yeah.";
   myString.erase(std::remove(myString.begin(), myString.end(), '\n'), 
                                                      myString.end());
   std::cout << myString<< std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
This is  a test. Let's go on.  Yeah
```

---

> **Solution 2**: To remove `"\n"` from the string and save each split at `\n` to a vector. (un-efficient)

Replace all `\n` occurance with some other charectors, which doesn't exist in the string (here I have chosen `;`). Then parse with the help of `std::stringstream` and `std::getline` as follows. [**SEE LIVE HERE**](https://www.ideone.com/57Nesd)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
   std::string myString = "This is \n a test. Let's go on. \n Yeah.";
   std::replace(myString.begin(), myString.end(), '\n', ';');
   std::stringstream ssMyString(myString);
   std::string each_split;
   std::vector<std::string> vec;
   while(std::getline(ssMyString, each_split, ';')) vec.emplace_back(each_split);
   for(const auto& it: vec) std::cout << it << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
This is 
 a test. Let's go on. 
 Yeah.
```

---

> **Solution 3**: To remove `"\n"` from the string and save each split at `\n` to a vector.

Loop through the string and find positions(using `std::string::find`) where `\n`(end position) finds. Push back the substrings (`std::string::substr`) using the information of starting position and the number of charectors between start and end position. Each time update the start and end positions, so that look up will not start again from the beging of the input string. [**SEE LIVE HERE**](https://www.ideone.com/AANZRN)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    std::string myString = "This is \n a test. Let's go on. \n Yeah.";
    std::vector<std::string> vec;

    std::size_t start_pos = 0;
    std::size_t end_pos = 0;
    while ((end_pos = myString.find("\n", end_pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        vec.emplace_back(myString.substr(start_pos, end_pos - start_pos));
        start_pos = end_pos + 1;
        end_pos += 2;
    }
    vec.emplace_back(myString.substr(start_pos, myString.size() - start_pos)); // last substring

    for(const auto& it: vec) std::cout << it << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
This is 
 a test. Let's go on. 
 Yeah.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will have a look on the code later and you'll get your checkmark. `Hoch die Hände, Wochenende!`

Comment: Note in your second example the second argument to substr() is count, not position, so you probably want `end_pos - start_pos`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

class line : public std::string {};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &iss, line &line)
{
    std::getline(iss, line, '\n');
    return iss;
}

int main()
{

    std::istringstream iss("This is \n a test. Let's go on. \n Yeah.");
    std::vector<std::string> v(std::istream_iterator<line>{iss}, std::istream_iterator<line>{});

    // test
    for (auto const &s : v)
        std::cout << s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Basically make a new type of string which is line and use stream iterator to read whole lines straight to vector range constructor

Working demo: https://ideone.com/4qdfY2